# Create my own type in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I Have this YAML code of swagger and I need to create my own type (named MyOwnType).

If I use "MyOwnType" a compilation error occurs.

```
paths:
  /in/total:
    get:
      summary: My summary.
      description: My description.

      parameters:
        - name: total
          in: query
          description: Total.
          required: true
          type: MyOwnType # -- THIS LINE OCCURS ERROR --
          format: MyOwnType
      responses:
        201:
          description: Respose
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MyOwnType'

definitions:
  MyOwnType:
    properties:
      var:
        type: string
        description: data.
```

I created a definition "MyOwnType" and I can use like that: "$ref: '#/definitions/MyOwnType'" in schema.

But how can I use the "MyOwnType" definition on a parameter type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query parameter can not have a JSON Schema. If you want to have schema for your parameter you should change `in` of your parameter to `body` or `formData` and use `schema` key:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: '<enter your title>'
paths:
  /in/total:
    get:
      summary: My summary.
      description: My description.

      parameters:
        - name: total
          in: body
          description: Total.
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MyOwnType'
      responses:
        201:
          description: Respose
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MyOwnType'

definitions:
  MyOwnType:
    properties:
      var:
        type: string
        description: data.
```